# Question about headers and one inch margins

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr

I'm writing an application for the National Science Foundation (NSF) Graduate Fellowship (NSF GRFP) and they require you to have one inch margins. As I want to put the title of the proposal at the top of each page, I put in a header using the fancyhdr package. However, NSF requires that the application have one inch margins, and I was wondering if the header is one inch away from the edge of the page (it sure looks like it)?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Have you tried printing a page and measuring it?

Answer (score 2):

As you didn't provide a [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) we can only guess, here is mine:

```
\usepackage[margin=1in, showframe]{geometry}
```

The `showframe` option of the [geometry](https://www.google.com.br/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CC4QFjAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.ctan.org%2Fpkg%2Fgeometry&ei=X6hzVa_rLoHbgwThioCgBQ&usg=AFQjCNFEpLpsjTqhMrVG170dLBu0i4-MYA&bvm=bv.95039771,d.eXY) package will present you with lines where the margins are, this makes it very easy to spot it.